# C# max length of URL

Tags: c#, url

I have a huge problem. I write small servers in C#. My clients are JavaScript. JavaScript use HTTP GET to communicate because JavaScript must pass Same Origin Policy. It means I must use HTTP GET to comunication. Now I notice that C# cut (??) my URL.

I sended:

```
http://172.16.210.25:8000/?callback=ProxyApi.saveStat&cid=1343823765156_495&cidget=null&s[901]=1044!:!5878849%3B6658291%3B2964823%3B1178767%3B469747%3B481939%3B6431323%3B1032649%3B2750603%3B208057%3B9192763%3B6669071%3B2014351%3B6816157%3B3784367%3B1242929%3B4488073%3B7662331%3B2991731%3B6404357%3B8248091%3B1795603%3B4880191%3B3080303%3B4093847%3B4618063%3B7501937%3B2842849%3B6953249%3B7102679%3B5667853%3B9851873%3B5517823%3B6114539%3B6061597%3B7647599%3B4871873%3B400087%3B7514713%3B3958217%3B8163713%3B9560437%3B8229701%3B3408749%3B4432097%3B3353219%3B2936693%3B1343597%3B3490451%3B1266191%3B9125747%3B6152921%3B2689537%3B3796861%3B4987009%3B1206841%3B9278119%3B9499619%3B455627%3B6217051%3B7603201%3B8019079%3B5306033%3B8314939%3B2997221%3B3996221%3B3889649%3B1148507%3B9397139%3B4984949%3B6576473%3B3993247%3B676051%3B5%3B&s[902]=929!:!9012569%3B9836633%3B5239051%3B6102559%3B5944079%3B9749681%3B4007797%3B344821%3B9914917%3B1950227%3B982847%3B6610337%3B6734281%3B4213463%3B1620449%3B1745111%3B8005717%3B6740443%3B8290811%3B9652289%3B279557%3B9077213%3B169933%3B4785463%3B368521%3B5881487%3B5735711%3B189377%3B3417091%3B8616299%3B7168723%3B4220969%3B4493651%3B5067977%3B1646387%3B3925297%3B5990723%3B6826471%3B3040753%3B1449733%3B8905681%3B2502001%3B7304107%3B1022677%3B4966529%3B8679397%3B4319519%3B3991279%3B1128641%3B2148631%3B2215987%3B1135217%3B3846281%3B1049843%3B309937%3B2241691%3B8768581%3B6199693%3B7973921%3B9683627%3B9664957%3B4493023%3B2494729%3B3581167%3B8474597%3B1987919%3B6099271%3B&t=68999&pxid=142221422
```

But I got in string:

```
?callback=ProxyApi.saveStat&cid=1343823765156_495&cidget=null&s[901]=1044!:!5878849%3B6658291%3B2964823%3B1178767%3B469747%3B481939%3B6431323%3B1032649%3B2750603%3B208057%3B9192763%3B6669071%3B2014351%3B6816157%3B3784367%3B1242929%3B4488073%3B7662331%3B2991731%3B6404357%3B8248091%3B1795603%3B4880191%3B3080303%3B4093847%3B4618063%3B7501937%3B2842849%3B6953249%3B7102679%3B5667853%3B9851873%3B5517823%3B6114539%3B6061597%3B7647599%3B4871873%3B400087%3B7514713%3B3958217%3B8163713%3B9560437%3B8229701%3B3408749%3B4432097%3B3353219%3B2936693%3B1343597%3B3490451%3B1266191%3B9125747%3B6152921%3B2689537%3B3796861%3B4987009%3B1206841%3B9278119%3B9499619%3B455627%3B6217051%3B7603201%3B8019079%3B5306033%3B8314939%3B2997221%3B3996221%3B3889649%3B1148507%3B9397139%3B4984949%3B6576473%3B3993247%3B676051%3B5%3B&s[902]=929!:!9012569%3B9836633%3B5239051%3B6102559%3B5944079%3B9749681%3B4007797%3B344821%3B9914917%3B1950227%3B982847%3B6610337%3B6734281%3B4213463%3B1620449%3B1745111%3B8005717%3B6740443%3B8290811%3B9652289%3B279
```

I lost some important data.

Im listing using:

```
IPAddress local_ip = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName())[0];
TcpListener sockServer = new TcpListener(local_ip,Port);

sockServer.Start();
```

And

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(ThreadFunction), sockServer.AcceptSocket());
```

And inside ThreadFunction I have

```
static void ThreadFunction(Object param)
    {
        Socket socket = (Socket)param;
        proxy.Run(socket);
    }
```

Finally I read message using this:

```
int bytes = ReadMessage(socket, readBuf, ref strFromClient);
```

Can you help me pass problem with URL LENGHT or change method of listining (unknown Javscript clients send large messeage using HTTP GET.)

===================
EDIT

I try using IE, Chrome and FF. I sent

```
http://172.16.210.25:8000/?callback=ProxyApi.saveStat&cid=1343823765156_495&cidget=null&s[901]=1044!:!5878849%3B6658291%3B2964823%3B1178767%3B469747%3B481939%3B6431323%3B1032649%3B2750603%3B208057%3B9192763%3B6669071%3B2014351%3B6816157%3B3784367%3B1242929%3B4488073%3B7662331%3B2991731%3B6404357%3B8248091%3B1795603%3B4880191%3B3080303%3B4093847%3B4618063%3B7501937%3B2842849%3B6953249%3B7102679%3B5667853%3B9851873%3B5517823%3B6114539%3B6061597%3B7647599%3B4871873%3B400087%3B7514713%3B3958217%3B8163713%3B9560437%3B8229701%3B3408749%3B4432097%3B3353219%3B2936693%3B1343597%3B3490451%3B1266191%3B9125747%3B6152921%3B2689537%3B3796861%3B4987009%3B1206841%3B9278119%3B9499619%3B455627%3B6217051%3B7603201%3B8019079%3B5306033%3B8314939%3B2997221%3B3996221%3B3889649%3B1148507%3B9397139%3B4984949%3B6576473%3B3993247%3B676051%3B5%3B&s[902]=929!:!9012569%3B9836633%3B5239051%3B6102559%3B5944079%3B9749681%3B4007797%3B344821%3B9914917%3B1950227%3B982847%3B6610337%3B6734281%3B4213463%3B1620449%3B1745111%3B8005717%3B6740443%3B8290811%3B9652289%3B279557%3B9077213%3B169933%3B4785463%3B368521%3B5881487%3B5735711%3B189377%3B3417091%3B8616299%3B7168723%3B4220969%3B4493651%3B5067977%3B1646387%3B3925297%3B5990723%3B6826471%3B3040753%3B1449733%3B8905681%3B2502001%3B7304107%3B1022677%3B4966529%3B8679397%3B4319519%3B3991279%3B1128641%3B2148631%3B2215987%3B1135217%3B3846281%3B1049843%3B309937%3B2241691%3B8768581%3B6199693%3B7973921%3B9683627%3B9664957%3B4493023%3B2494729%3B3581167%3B8474597%3B1987919%3B6099271%3B&t=68999&pxid=142221422
```

But I always get

```
GET /?callback=ProxyApi.saveStat&cid=1343823765156_495&cidget=null&s[901]=1044!:!5878849%3B6658291%3B2964823%3B1178767%3B469747%3B481939%3B6431323%3B1032649%3B2750603%3B208057%3B9192763%3B6669071%3B2014351%3B6816157%3B3784367%3B1242929%3B4488073%3B7662331%3B2991731%3B6404357%3B8248091%3B1795603%3B4880191%3B3080303%3B4093847%3B4618063%3B7501937%3B2842849%3B6953249%3B7102679%3B5667853%3B9851873%3B5517823%3B6114539%3B6061597%3B7647599%3B4871873%3B400087%3B7514713%3B3958217%3B8163713%3B9560437%3B8229701%3B3408749%3B4432097%3B3353219%3B2936693%3B1343597%3B3490451%3B1266191%3B9125747%3B6152921%3B2689537%3B3796861%3B4987009%3B1206841%3B9278119%3B9499619%3B455627%3B6217051%3B7603201%3B8019079%3B5306033%3B8314939%3B2997221%3B3996221%3B3889649%3B1148507%3B9397139%3B4984949%3B6576473%3B3993247%3B676051%3B5%3B&s[902]=929!:!9012569%3B9836633%3B5239051%3B6102559%3B5944079%3B9749681%3B4007797%3B344821%3B9914917%3B1950227%3B982847%3B6610337%3B6734281%3B4213463%3B1620449%3B1745111%3B8005717%3B6740443%3B8290811%3B9652289%3B279
```

Look

```
 private Byte[] readBuf = new Byte[2048];
 int bytes = ReadMessage(socket, readBuf, ref strFromClient);
```

My bytes always are to 1024. Where can be limits of there?

Comment: As @Shai answered the truncation happens at the browser - nothing to do with C#.

Comment: As @Shai mentions in his answer, I really think you might need to rethink your approach. Even if the limit is ~2000 chars, I'm picturing you're gonna run in to this problem later as well when your requests grow even bigger...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was careless. 
Function ReadMessage is function from own class. And it wrote:

```
sock.Receive(buf, 1024, 0);
```

Of course I fix:

```
sock.Receive(buf,buf.Length,0);
```

And Now it runs.
Thank for your answers.

Answer (score 4):

HTTP GET requests are usually limited to ~2000 characters (client-wise, that is)

Here's a [reference](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427) from MS

GET is not intended for sending large amount of data, that's why it's called *GET*... try to provide more information regarding your client and we might be able to offer you an alternative

Comment: @YngveB.Nilsen well it depends alot on the limitations the client has. for example, this length might varey between versions of Internet explorer

Comment: @YngveB.Nilsen - Different browsers and different versions of the same browser will have different limits to the maximum URL length they allow.

Comment: @Oded - Of course... I do think the latest update on this answer is key though. Rethinking the design...